# Class weighting during validation in Keras

Tags: neural-network, classification, keras, class-imbalance

I would like to know if the class weighting is also used in evaluating the loss in the validation data during the training. If not, is there a way to adjust the fit() function so that it takes into account the class weighting during the validation loss calculation.

Comment: I wonder why you want to add weights to the class during validation!!

Answer (score 4):

As described in the tensorflow docs[1], `validation_data` can be a tuple `(inputs, targets, sample_weights)`.  So, you can use this parameter for class weighting during the validation loss calculation.

---

[1] https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit

Comment: This is sample weight, which means that I have to check for each class sample and make a vector that has the right class weight for each sample

Comment: @moh Any idea how to supply class weight for validation data when using a generator?